# TextBox display with 2digit decimal value in MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

The textbox  decimal value has this format "0,0000" (, is the decimal separator). I'd like have only 2 decimal. How can I do this ?

**My model has:**

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal DisplayOrder { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayOrder)
```

But it doesn't works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: My text box have the vale 0.0000...But i need 0.00

Comment: So it's still outputting "0.0000" regardless of what you change in the `DisplayFormat` specification?

Comment: I change 0:00## to this one

Answer (score 3):

You may refer to this topic for more info about decimal format in MVC3
[Decimal Format in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428289/mvc3-decimal-truncated-to-2-decimal-places-on-edit)

And this link for a similar problem 
[Formatting decimal in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870931/how-to-show-a-decimal-corretly-formatted-in-0-00-format)

If none of the above worked you can try converting your number to string and passing it to this function.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Formatting a given number to 0,00
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    string NumberFormatting(string number)
    {
        if (number.Contains(','))
        {
            string[] str = number.Split(',');
            if (str[1].Length == 1)
            {
                number += "0";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            number += ",00";
        }
        return DecreaseNumberDigits(number);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To allow only two digits after the decimal mark
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    string DecreaseNumberDigits(string number)
    {
        if (number.Contains(','))
        {
            string[] str = number.Split(',');
            if (str[1].Length > 2)
                number = str[0] + "," + str[1].ToCharArray()[0].ToString() + str[1].ToCharArray()[1].ToString();
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expression** for do your job.

Try like below.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "Price must can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
public decimal DisplayOrder { get; set; }
```

For more information check [**Regular Expression Library Here**](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

I hope this will help to you.